# Белый цвет вдруг становится черным

Tags: java, android

На экране - Bitmap, при проведении по экрану рисуется белая линия от места начала нажатия до пальца.
В какой-то момент все линии вдруг становятся черными и новые линии тоже будут черным, а я хочу чтобы они всегда были белыми.

```
bitmap.setPixel(i,j,Color.argb(255,255,255,255));
```

[image][image: 2]

Answer (score 3):

Нашел причину и решение..

Это было из-за темного режима на телефоне..

Решение - сделать приложение только в светлом режиме

```
AppCompatDelegate.setdefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

Comment: а решение-то какое?

Comment: Дописал ответ..